Solution of differential equation
For what $k$ the differential equation $$(1-x^2)y^{\prime\prime}-2xy^\prime+kxy=0$$ has a solution (other than the null solution) such that $\left. \frac{dy}{du}\right |_{u=\pm \infty}=0$, $y^\prime=\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $x=\tanh{u}$?

For sure you mean "other than the null solution", since $y\equiv 0$ is a solution having the desired property for every $k$.

Уеs, of course. In fact it was shown numerically in https://arxiv.org/abs/2407.10787 that such a solution exists for example for $k\approx 29.056$. But how this can be proved analytically?

The equation is singular at $x=\pm1$, so you should explain what is a "solution" which is defined on the whole real line.

I have corrected the formulation.

Maybe you mean $\tanh u$ instead of $\tan u$?

Yes. I'm sorry, too many mistakes in formulation.

Still a factor of 2 is missing. The given equation has solutions at $k = 0, 14.52799787, 42.04852871, 83.30442543,$ $ 138.3077972,$ $207.0605917, \ldots$. These numbers are eigenvalues of a related Schrödinger equation with $u$- (or $x$-) dependent potential and given boundary conditions. Using a shooting method from say $x=1$ downwards the equations shows typical oscillations in $k$, and every finite solution at $x=-1$ yields one eigenvalue.

Yes, conventions in the cited paper are such that their $k$ is twice as big as the $k$ from the question.
